# VBA For Excel, Trying to get max / Min value for each row in within range.

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to work out how to get the maximum and min value for each range within a row within a sheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("API-VAL")

LastRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
.Range("BU1:BU1 +(LastRow)").Formula = "=Max(BD1:BS1)" ***- Error in this row.
.Range("BV1:BV1048576").Formula = "=Min(BD1:BS1)"

End With
```

I'm getting a "Runtime error -'1004'" Application-defined or object-defined error. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Range("BU1:BU" & CStr(LastRow)).Formula = "=Max(BD1:BS1)"
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly, been hitting my head off the wall with this one. I will remember CSTr in future. :)

Comment: The best way to express your pleasure is a click to accept any of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

.Range("BU1:BU" & LastRow).Formula = "=Max(BD1:BS1)"